# Can electron-forge be used with Electron 3.0?

Tags: electron, electron-forge

I would like to use some Electron 3.0 new APIs in my electron-forge application, but I am not finding any information of which electron version is electron-forge supporting?
I am currently running electron-forge 5.2.2.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: You can change electron version in package.json.

Comment: Yes, I know how to upgrade electron, my question is: will electron-forge still work after I upgrade electron?

Comment: I don't think electron-forge itself depends on specific electron version. But your program may need to change some code for electron api changes.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems actually that electron-forge is installing its own version of electron as part of dependencies of electron-prebuilt-compile. So you can't actually upgrade yourself.